# Как сделать вывод сообщения после нажатия на кнопку?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Пытаюсь вывести через `callback_data`, но бот ничего не выводит и просто присылает точно такое же сообщение

```php
$inline_keyboard_themes = [[['text' => 'Тема 1', 'callback_data' => "Ответ 1"], ['text' => 'Тема 2', 'callback_data' => "Ответ 2"], ['text' => 'Тема 3', 'callback_data' => "Ответ 3"]]];

$post = [
    'chat_id' => $user_id,
    'text' => 'Выберите основную тему, по которой у вас возник вопрос:',
    'reply_markup' => inline_keyboard($inline_keyboard_themes)
];

telegram('sendMessage', $post);
```

На нажатие любой кнопки должен выводиться ответ, но присылается точно такое же сообщение

[image: img]

Comment: Кнопки - это просто элемент, нажатие должен обрабатывать обработчик

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется вы недостаточно хорошо ознакомились с тем, как работают inline-кнопки в Telegram. При нажатии на кнопку пользователем, Telegram создает новый [`Update`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update) с типом `callback_query`. Вы должны обработать этот update и выполнить какое-то действие в соответствии payload-информацией, которую вы указываете в `callback_data`.

Для ответа на `callback_query` вы должны использовать метод [`answerCallbackQuery`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery).